# React Select not showing errors when validating with Formik and Yup

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select, yup

Hi guys I am using react-select in my project along with Formik and Yup for validation
Even though I see an error in error object in the console but I am not able to show that error on the frontend

Here is the code below

```
export default function FormSection({
  onContinueButton,
  allFormValues,
  holders,
}) {
  console.log(holders, "hol12");

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstBirthDate: "",
      firstSmoker: "",
      secondBirthDate: "",
      secondSmoker: "",
    },

    onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      console.log(formik.errors);
      console.log(formik.values, "valqwqrwe");

      setSubmitting(false);
      allFormValues(formik.values);
      console.log(values);
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchemaSectionTwo,
  });
  const options = [
    { value: "Não", label: "Não" },
    { value: "Sim", label: "Sim" },
  ];

  const handleChangeFirstHolder = (selectedOption) => {
    // this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
    formik.setFieldValue("firstSmoker", selectedOption);
  };

  console.log(formik.errors, "********");

  console.log("touchhhhhhhhhhhhhh", formik.touched.firstSmoker);
  return (
    <div className="secondSection">
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <p className="tab-text">É fumador?</p>
          <Select
            value={formik.values.firstSmoker}
            name="firstSmoker"
            onChange={handleChangeFirstHolder}
            options={options}
            className="select-smoker"
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          />
          {formik.errors.firstSmoker && formik.touched.firstSmoker && (
            <div className="formik-errors">{formik.errors.firstSmoker}</div>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>

        <br />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

so when I `console.log(formik.erros)` i see the error which I want to show to the user, but the `console.log(formik.touched.firstSmoker)` is always undefined even when I click on Select tag and then without choosing an option click outside of it, the touch value should be true as soon as I click but it isn't happening

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly tell Formik that the input's been touched. The simplest way to do this is by placing a `setTouched()` somewhere - such as inside handler `onBlur()`

```
 <Select
   value={formik.values.firstSmoker}
   name="firstSmoker"
   onChange={handleChangeFirstHolder}
   options={options}
   className="select-smoker"
   onBlur={()=> {
       formik.setTouched({ firstSmoker: true });
   }}
/>
```